# How to access a bean definition from BeanPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We register some beans with custom bean definition, in a BeanPostProcessor we need to access the bean definition

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
```

I can make it ApplicationContextAware and then do:

```
((ConfigurableApplicationContext)applicationContext).getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinition(beanName)
```

but is it assured that the applicationContext is always ConfigurableApplicationContext?
Is there another way to access the bean definition from a BeanPostProcessor?

Comment: Why would you need that? The `BeanPostProcessor` is for operating on bean instances not `BeanDefinities` (the recipes of the beans). Why would you need the definition for a bean that already originated from that very same definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access `BeanDefinition` instances, you should use `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` instead of `BeanPostProcessor`.

**BeanFactoryPostProcessor**

> Allows for custom modification of an application context's bean
>   definitions, adapting the bean property values of the context's
>   underlying bean factory. A BeanFactoryPostProcessor may interact with and modify bean definitions, but never bean instances.

**BeanPostProcessor**

> Factory hook that allows for custom modification of new bean
>   instances, e.g. checking for marker interfaces or wrapping them with
>   proxies.

Comment: We register beans dynamically with a ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar, we keep some attributes as metadata on the beans definitions. 
then we configure the beans , populate properties, with a BeanPostProcessor, at that stage we need the metadata from the bean definition. the bean definitions where decided based on Annotations metadata on the importing class and at BeanPostProcessor we don't know the importing class.

Comment: What kind of metadata you keep in bean definition? What is their purpose?